# Calculate the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n(n+1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have already proven that

$$\int_0^1 \ln(1-x)\ln (x)\mathrm d x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n(n+1)^2}.$$

So now I want so calculate

> $$S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n(n+1)^2}.$$

I think I should use the fact that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

and I know using Wolfram Alpha that $S=2-\frac{\pi^2}6$.

So finally I will get

$$\int_0^1 \ln(1-x)\ln (x)\mathrm d x=2-\frac{\pi^2}6.$$

But how to calculate $S$ ?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
[(partial fraction decomposition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Comment: J'espère que c'est une vaste blague le CRCG ...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Vaste blague en effet ! Le principe étant d'apporter un peu de fantaisie dans les mathématiques :) N'hésite pas à nous contacter !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m }\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{m}{m+1}=1-\frac{1}{m+1}$$ the sum is $1$when the $m\rightarrow \infty$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n(n+1)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{n+1}) -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=1 -\sum_{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$=1-(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1)=2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: Note that, as written, the answer is not correct since $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. You must write the series as a limit of a finite sum and only after that you can do these manipulations.

Comment: It is not important that the result is correct. The false implies the true and the false. The point is that in this site we want learn mathematics and this answer, as written, is not correct.

Comment: It seems you don't understand the huge difference between $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n})-(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}) = \infty-\infty$ , and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{n+1}) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N  (\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{n+1}) = \lim_{N \to \infty} 1-\frac{1}{N+1} = 1$

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is interesting to see another way to solve the integral. Recalling the definition of Beta function $$B\left(a,b\right)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}\left(1-x\right)^{b-1}dx,\, a,b>0
 $$ we have that $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial a\partial b}B\left(a,b\right)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}\log\left(x\right)\left(1-x\right)^{b-1}\log\left(1-x\right)dx
 $$ but since $$B\left(a,b\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b\right)}{\Gamma\left(a+b\right)}\tag{1}
 $$ we have that $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial a\partial b}B\left(a,b\right)=B\left(a,b\right)\left(\left(\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(a\right)-\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(a+b\right)\right)\left(\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(b\right)-\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(a+b\right)\right)-\psi^{\left(1\right)}\left(b\right)\right)
 $$ where $\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(x\right),\psi^{\left(1\right)}\left(x\right)
 $ are respectively the [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and [trigamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function) function. So $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(x\right)\log\left(1-x\right)dx=\left.\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial a\partial b}B\left(a,b\right)\right|_{a=1,b=1}
 $$ $$=B\left(1,1\right)\left(\left(\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(1\right)-\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(2\right)\right)^{2}-\psi^{\left(1\right)}\left(2\right)\right)
 $$ and now using $(1)$, and $$\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}-\gamma
 $$ $$\psi^{\left(1\right)}\left(n\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(k+n\right)^{2}}
 $$ we can conclude $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(x\right)\log\left(1-x\right)dx=\color{red}{2-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}}$$ as wanted.

Comment: It made me think to that http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts :P